# Getting lock file syntax error when importing portalocker on python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I'm actually trying to import sacrebleu, but sacrebleu uses portalocker, and I get the following error (the full error below):

```
  File “run.py”, line 52, in <module>
    import sacrebleu
  File “/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/local_nmt/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sacrebleu/__init__.py”, line 21, in <module>
    from .utils import smart_open, SACREBLEU_DIR, download_test_set
  File “/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/local_nmt/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sacrebleu/utils.py”, line 8, in <module>
    import portalocker
  File “/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/local_nmt/lib/python3.5/site-packages/portalocker/__init__.py”, line 41
    LOCK_EX: constants.LockFlags = constants.LockFlags.EXCLUSIVE
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python version is 3.7.9!

Comment: Likely not! Your conda env may be using a different version of Python to what you expect!

Comment: You are not on Python 3.7 but 3.5 and that does not support this type annotation yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, resolved — needed Python version 3.7 and was running in an env of 3.5.